# apply logic condition to decimal values in awk

Tags: bash, awk, logic

I have many tables that look like this:

```
Gnl_182 -2,05   -1,57   2,38095238095238    Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_182 -1,47   -2,19   0   Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_182 -1,63   -1,82   4,16666666666667    Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_182 1,61290322580645    0   2,63157894736842    Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_182 9,09090909090909    -1,46   0   Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_182 -3,36   -3,02   1,0752688172043 Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_182 1,66666666666667    -1,37   2,22222222222222    Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_182 1,44927536231884    -1,14   3,7037037037037 Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_182 1,92307692307692    1,14942528735632    0   Q   Rob_4   -100
Gnl_182 1,49253731343284    -1,15   3,44827586206897    Q   Rob_4   -100,684642156432   1,9660323361869
Gnl_1964    1,36986301369863    -1,03   -1,47   Q   Rob_4   -2,73908329200197   4,40585349069822
Gnl_1964    -1,02   -1,04   -2,53   Q   Rob_4   -2,73908329200197   4,40585349069822
Gnl_1964    0   -1,17   -1,55   Q   Rob_4   -2,73908329200197   4,40585349069822
Gnl_2006    -3,63   1,49253731343284    2,08333333333333    Q   Rob_4   -23,1216666666667   23,6583333333333
Gnl_2006    4,16666666666667    2,04081632653061    2,63157894736842    Q   Rob_4   -23,1216666666667   23,6583333333333
```

I want to verify that the values in the second column are in the range defined by the last two values. If this condition is matched I would like to print the all line.

I was quite sure that this code will work

```
awk -F "\t" '{if($2>=$7 && $2<=$8) print}' file_name.txt > test.txt
```

but it does not. For example for the first group (Gnl_182) it removes the line containing in column two the values:

```
9,09
-1,47
-1,63
```

Wheres, just the line containing

```
9,09
```

should be removed

I really do not see what I am missing here. Something wrong with the decimals?
Thank you!

Comment: I copied you input and It didn't contain tabs, it may be the something nasty with copy and paste, so I replaced '\s+' by '\t' and your code worked perfectly, so I suggest you to check if the tabs are correct, you can do that using `cat -A` you should see `^I` to indicate tab.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. You are right. This is because I copied it from openoffice. Anyway I checked and there are tabs. I figured out that the comas were the problem. When I change comas with dots my code works.